# Number of tags versus number of views

Tags: support, tags

I noticed that some questions with many tags get low views. Is that a coincidence? If I want to avoid getting low views, should I use fewer or more tags? I have no intention of abusing tags to artificially *increase* the number of views; I just don't want a *decrease* in views due to not understanding how this works.

Comment: I suspect this is an illusory correlation. (We'll need the data to know.) However, bear in mind that the data would be endogenous. That is, there may be nothing about having more tags that leads to lower views. For example, someone who doesn't really know what they are asking or how to ask it may add a lot of tags & also ask an unfocused & uninteresting question, such that the tags & the views are independent effects of the same cause. FWIW, I don't think it's abuse to use the system as best you can to get deserved attention to your questions.

Comment: Thanks! The correlation might indeed be illusory. I just wanted to see if there is some simple mechanism associating tags and views so as to avoid any negative consequences.

Comment: Generally speaking more tags will (very slightly) tend to increase views, since people searching for those tags will be more likely to find the post. On the other hand if more tags were associated with a less focused or unclear question that might lead to less attention.

Comment: I remember some years ago, having the same impression for my questions in StackOverflow SE. But if it was more than an impression, can't say.